# how to plot multiple animated functions on the same plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i want to plot two animated functions on the same plot to compare between two functions , lets say for example exp(-x**2) and exp(x**2)
i know how to animate a function here is the code i used to animate the function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
%matplotlib qt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'r', animated=True)
f = np.linspace(-3, 3, 200)
def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.25, 2)
    ln.set_data(xdata,ydata)
    return ln,
def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.exp(-frame**2))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=f,enter code here
                    init_func=init, blit=True, interval = 2.5,repeat=False)
plt.show()



enter code here
```

and by the same method we can plot the other function but how do we show them on the same plot

Comment: Add another line, like `ln2, = plt.plot(...)` and update that line in the same way you're doing it for `ln` already.

Comment: i tried but got this error unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: That indentation error is just basic python. Make sure to always use the same number of spaces (best 4) for indentation.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comment, adding another line will work. Here is a working example with exp(-x^2) and exp(x^2), I also changed the limits to see both better:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata0, ydata1 = [], [], []
ln0, = plt.plot([], [], 'r', animated=True)
ln1, = plt.plot([], [], 'b', animated=True)
f = np.linspace(-3, 3, 200)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.25, 10)
    ln0.set_data(xdata,ydata0)
    ln1.set_data(xdata,ydata1)
    return ln0, ln1

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata0.append(np.exp(-frame**2))
    ydata1.append(np.exp(frame**2))
    ln0.set_data(xdata, ydata0)
    ln1.set_data(xdata, ydata1)
    return ln0, ln1,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=f,
                    init_func=init, blit=True, interval=2.5, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

For the gif below I changed the `plt.show()` line to be `ani.save('animated_exp.gif', writer='imagemagick')` and changed the interval to be 25.

[image: gif created with example code]